# How to specify database connection using statement method in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am running a raw query on Laravel using `DB::statement()` method. This statement needs to fetch data from my secondary database.

I wonder if there is any clean way to specify database connection to this method instead of using database name prefix before all fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `connection` method, which accepts any connection name stored in the `config/database.php` file:

```php
DB::connection('pgsql')->statement('your statement here...');
```

You can read more in the [Using Multiple Database Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#accessing-connections) Documentation.

Comment: @JON The [Database Connections Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#using-multiple-database-connections) show that the API works exactly the same. I am using connections in one of my projects which runs on 5.6 and it works just fine, so the problem must be with your code not the Laravel API.